# SQL Server Pivot Function Understanding

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Source    TableName     Detail     active_status     RowCount
a          table_one     stuff      active               500
b          table_two     stuff_2    active               750
c          table_three   stuff_3    inactive            1000
d          table_four    stuff_4    active               200
e          table_five    stuff_5    inactive             200
```

What I want is this result:

```
result      a     b      c     d    e
result    500   750   1000   200 2000
```

Here is the SQL Query I am using:

```
select 'results' as results, ['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e']
from (select [source], [rowcount] from ParentStaged) as src_tbl
pivot
(
    sum([rowcount])
    for source in (['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'])
) as pivot_tbl;
```

This produces this:

```
results    a      b    c    d    e
results null   null null null null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify column values used as headers without quotes in your pivot,

For example:

```
select 'results' as results, a, b, c, d, e
from (select [source], rowcnt from ParentStaged) as src_tbl
pivot
(
    sum(rowcnt)
    for source in (a, b, c, d, e)
) as pivot_tbl;
```

OR

```
select 'results' as results, [a], [b], [c], [d], [e]
from (select [source], rowcnt from ParentStaged) as src_tbl
pivot
(
    sum(rowcnt)
    for source in ([a], [b], [c], [d], [e])
) as pivot_tbl;
```

Comment: Why does the quotes make a difference? I thought I would need the quotes, at least without brackets.

Comment: @LunchBox the brackets `[some name]` allow you to use a name, which was forbidden otherwise. You can use them always, but you must use them, if your name includes forbidden characters. A name like `['a']` will use the full three character string `'a'` as column name.

Comment: oh, duh, I was thinking about something else. Sorry, too many languages. Thank you!